# Some questions about bi-vector field and Poisson bracket.

Tags: symplectic-geometry, exterior-algebra, poisson-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. Then we can define a Poisson bracket of $f$ and $g$ where $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M)$ by
$$\{f,g\}=p(df\wedge dg)\text{ }(1)$$
where $p\in\Gamma(T^2M)$, $p=\omega^{-1}:T^*M\to TM$.

I want to connect/understand this definition with the definition that $\{f,g\}=\omega(X_f,X_g)\text{ }(2)$.

Since the symplectic form $\omega$ is non-degenerate, then we can see that we have the isomorphism
$$\omega:TM\to T^*M$$
given by $X\to i_X\omega$. Then if we given a smooth function $f$, we can generate the vector field $X_f$ using the identity
$$i_{X_f}\omega=df$$
i.e. we literally can define our vector field by $X_f=\omega^{-1}(df)$.

- Does the definition $(1)$ come before $(2)$  since we first need to find $df$ and $dg$ in order to obtain our vector fields $X_f$ and $X_g$?
- Why $p\in\Gamma(\bigwedge^2 TM)$ but $p$ is defined on $\bigwedge^2 T^*M$? Is the map defined by
  $$p(df\wedge dg)=p(df)\wedge p(dg)$$
  where we have the following compositions of maps
  $$M\to T^*M\wedge T^*M\to TM\wedge TM?$$

Comment: To your first question: (1) and (2) are equivalent definitions, I am not sure what you mean by "does (1) come before (2)". To your second question: try first to make sense of it on vector spaces, i.e. let $V$ be a vector space and think of $p\in V\wedge V$ and similar of $\mathrm{d}f,\mathrm{d}g\in V^*$ . Does that help?